# How to create test resources folder manually for unit test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven, junit

the sample application i am working on doesn't have a resources folder in test, i don't know why, so i am trying to create the resources folder in test manually as follows:

from eclipse: on the **java resources** > **new source folder** > **src/test/resources**

i can see now that the resource folder appears in test package, but question is, is there's **any additional configuration** should i do to **maven** or **spring** or **unit test** so i can work with resources folder and load files from it ?

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You either use maven standard directory layout (then maven includes it automatically) or you point maven to the resources in your pom file in build section as follows:

```
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Then you have the resources on classpath.

Comment: well, i tried the test based on the way i described above and it worked fine BTW, what will be the use of above config ?

Comment: bTW, i found the following tag in pom file for resources: `<resources>
   
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>

  </resources>` will the test need filtering=true too ?

Comment: @Mika: Depends if you want any substitutions done at build time in the resources files. If you want that, you need filtering; if not, you don't. (Which do you need? Depends on what you're doing, but you probably don't want substitutions in image files…)

Comment: As Donal wrote ... fitlering replaces variables ${var} with their values. More here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh - I want maven to create main/resources and test/resources for me. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I post another answer for **Gradle** users

Edit *.classpath* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    ...
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    ...
</classpath>
```